# Inspection to ensure all variable declarations are initialised

Tags: java, intellij-idea

My company's coding standards dictate that all variables/fields etc must be assigned at declaration (with at least null if there's no actual value yet).

Is there an Intellij inspection which will highlight when a variable has been declared without having been assigned in the same operation?

Edit:
I'm aware that the standard itself isn't the best standard. As I said in a comment, a lot of our Java coding standards are based off of C conventions and the whims of the CEO. I'm not looking for an answer on whether or not the standard is correct (and I'm not saying you're wrong but you're preaching to the choir anyway) but for a way, in Intellij, that I can ease some of the hassle I get when it comes time for code reviews, by having had it already pointed out to me by Intellij.

Comment: Note that a coding standard like that can actually be *harmful*. If your compiler can detect paths where the variable is used uninitialized, then you have prevented it from doing so, and moved the detection of a bug from compile-time to run-time.

Answer (score 0):

In java it is unnecessary requirement. Read [JLS 4.12.5](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.12.5).

You can always say to your boss, that object and class variables (fields and static fields) are always initiated by default value: `null` for references, `0` for primitives and `false` for `boolean` type. So explicit reinitilization of them with `null` or `0` values is redundant.

For local variables which aren't initialized `Intellij IDEA` will point their usage with error-style highlighting, because it is compile-time error if you use variable's value which wasn't previously initialized.

Comment: I understand that it's not necessary, but I've been down this road already of trying to convince them of that. A lot of the senior people still code in Vim/Emacs and the argument goes that it's clearer this way.

Either way, I'm not in a position to get the coding standards changed..

Comment: If they do this, they don't know specification of java. It is unrelated to used IDE

Comment: I know they don't, a lot of the coding standards that we use for Java code are based around C conventions, you're preaching to the choir on the correctness of the standards, I'm just looking for something that will ease some of my hassle when it comes time for code reviewing.

Comment: Then answer will be: *there is not such function in Intellij IDEA*, because it is unnecessary for 99% of developers. But, you can implement your own plugin for that purposes.